# ZRevRangeByScore function in golang for redis giving unexpected result when count is 0

Tags: go, redis

I am using the following for redis client in go 
  https://github.com/go-redis/redis
I have a problem in the below shown code snippet.

```
vals, err = this.Cli.ZRevRangeByScore(sortedSet, redis.ZRangeBy{
Min:    strconv.Itoa(int(query.Since.Unix())),
Max:    "+inf",
Offset: 0,
Count:  int64(query.maxEvents),
}).Result()
```

Whenever my query.maxEvents is 0, instead of empty set(expected), I am getting whole set as a response(unexpected). Why is this happening ?

Comment: I believe this line is the culprit: https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/e1263fea7be54f2d1eac6da7b4e86e623a517f4e/commands.go#L1495. (Essentially, passing a 0 is like not passing a count at all.) I'd suggest opening a task on that GitHub project if you consider this to be a bug. (In the meantime, you'll probably have to special-case 0.)